# How to replace a random IP-address in a file (Perl, Windows)

Tags: windows, file, perl, replace, ip-address

How can I replace a random (unknown) IP-address in a TXT file using Windows Perl?
(unfortunately I only found solutions mostly for Linux/sed)

My textfile contains FTP commands, containing only one IP address:

```
open ftp://user:password@123.123.123.123
cd c:/temp
mkdir newdir
```

etc.

I tried this, but it did not change anything.

```
perl -pe s/[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}/10.10.111.222/g FtpCommands.txt > FtpCommands_mod.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) is a good starting point for matching an IP address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file has an IPv4 address, using the [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) module makes this an easy one-liner:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -pe "s/$RE{net}{IPv4}/10.10.111.222/" FtpCommands.txt > FtpCommands_mod.txt
```

Comment: Use double quotes `... "s/$RE{net}{IPv4}/10.10.111.222/"` on Windows command line

Comment: Thank you to you both! It works on Windows using Regexp module and also without it:  
`perl -MRegexp::Common=net -pe "s/$RE{net}{IPv4}/10.10.111.222/" FtpCommands.txt > FtpCommands_mod.txt`  <br/>
`perl -pe "s/[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}/10.10.111.222/" FtpCommands.txt > FtpCommands_mod.txt`

Comment: @mob Done. Looks funny, though. I assume the standard windows shell doesn't use $ for variable substitution then?